# Angular route view

Tags: angularjs

next situation

```
when('/contact', { controller: contactController, resolve: contactController.resolve, activetab: 'contact', templateUrl: 'views/contact.html' }).
```

I'ts page where window was created, and when i try close window from index.html, i have error Uncaught TypeError: $$(...).close is not a function, i think becouse browser not can view element? how send close param to contact.html ? becouse if i go to pag cotact.htlm, and click close there window close.

thanks.

Comment: What you mean by "closing" the page? You mean changing the view?

Comment: i try remove html element from view in contact.html

Comment: Not enough details given here about *"page where window was created"*. You need to look at where in your code that error is thrown also.